# how to convert folder into Zip file in codeigniter where folder contains some image file

Tags: codeigniter

i have some doubts in zipping the folder in codeigniter.Actually i have some image files in the folder and i was trying to zip this folder in codegiter. I have view file where i have written "Download all file" button. On clicking this button i have to take the folder and zip it.
My view file:
I have written the button "Download All Files" inside the anchor tag.

```
<tr>
    <td align="right">
        <?php  if(isset($AppData) && !empty($AppData)) { 
          $applicantNo = $AppData[0]['appid']; ?>
        <a href='<?php echo base_url("admin/downloadAllFileZip/$applicantNo");?>'><input type="submit" name="download" value="Download All Files" /></a> 
         <?php } ?>

    </td>
   </tr>
```

Controller code:
Inside admin.php controller file i have the below method

```
public function downloadAllFileZip($appId) 
    {

        $path = file_get_contents(base_url().'files/'.$appId);          
        $applicant_id = $appId;
        $this->zip->add_data($applicant_id,$path);
        $this->zip->archive('/files/'.$applicant_id);       
        $this->zip->download($applicant_id); 

    }
```

But when I am clicking the " Download all file " button the popup window for zipping is comming and after downloading its showing 1kb file but there is no image on that file. I can able to zip single image file as a zip file but not able to zip the entire folder. Please help me how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

add your all file like this. For Ex:

```
foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
    $this->zip->read_file($row->filename);
}

$this->zip->download('files_backup.zip');
```

Comment: No need to take foreach ($query->result() as $row). I am not writing any sql query

Comment: it's just for reference you can add your image file like this way

Comment: Just i am passing the folder name in the parameters from the anchor link and in the controller i am taking the folder name from the path and zipping it that it.

Answer (score 0):

To archive all files within a folder use `$this->zip->read_dir();` method. Example,

```
$path = '/path/to/folder';
$this->zip->read_dir($path); 
$this->zip->archive('/path/to/folder/foldername.zip');
```

For more info. please have a look: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/zip.html

Comment: I used $this->zip->add_dir(); above $this->zip->read_file() i can able to download the folder but inside the folder there is no image files.

Comment: Please check for the folder permission, it should be 755 or 777.

Comment: Not in server. Individual image pics i can download as zip using the same code. I can able to download the folder but the inside the folder no pics are available.

Answer (score 0):

**Zip library permits you to create Zip archives**

```
$this->load->library('zip');
```

**Give path of your folder that you want to add in archive**

```
 $file_name='backup['.date('d-m-Y-H:i:s').'].zip';
 $this->zip->read_dir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/uploads/images",FALSE);
 $this->zip->download($file_name);
```

I think give absolute path is better way for archived folder on specific folder

Comment: without adding $this->zip->add_dir($appId); on clicking the Download all files button its redirecting to blank page so i have added. I can able to download the zip file but the folder is empty

Comment: First open one image from your folder to browser and paste same url in read dir and check its works or not like `$this->zip->read_file($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/uploads/img/img1.png",FALSE);`

Comment: ya its possible i can able see the image, but i have download the entire folder.

Comment: In my project, files is the folder name which contains candidate registration number as a folder name which contains documents.

Comment: Then the above code should work out with `read_dir` and no matter which type of things is contains in your folder.@RagithThomas

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->load->library('zip');
$path = '/path/to/your_directory/';    
$this->zip->read_dir($path);    
$this->zip->download('my_backup.zip');
```